# To check that value in a textbox is inputted only from autocomplete values.

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, autocomplete, dojo

I am Developing a web application. For inputting values i am using an auto complete which gets its data from the database.

```
$(document).ready(function hello(){
    var myVar1 = <%=request.getAttribute("variable1")%>
      $("input#assignedbyid").autocomplete({
    source: myVar1
      });
});
```

The above given example gives me a set of values which are picked up from a database using `JDBC` and `json` code. AT any point of time the value in `myvar1` looks like this::

```
["Kapil","Mayur","Abhinav","Chandan"]
```

Which comes as a source for auto complete values.
My html code where my `input tag onfocus` calls up the `function hello().`

```
<div id="lets"><input dojoType="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" id="assignedbyid" name="assignedbyname"  required="true" onfocus="hello();" onblur="hi();"></div>
```

Now i want to have a validation check which checks that value entered by the user comes from auto complete values only`("Kapil","Mayur","Abhinav","Chandan")` and not any other value. I have this Code where in if no value is entered the text box shakes up`(onblur="hi();")`. in else part i want to that checking to be done.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 function periodical() {
            $('#lets').effect('shake', { times: 5 }, 200);
        };
          $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#lets').hide().css('display','').fadeIn(600);
                }); 
        function hi(){
            var dude = dojo.byId("assignedbyid").value;

            if(dude==""){
                periodical();}
            else{

            if(dude)
                myVar1

                alert("value entered");}
                };
</script>
```

My else part is incomplete for the time being. how can this be done ?. Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var V = $("#myInput").val();
if (V=="Kapil"||V=="Mayur"||V=="Abhinav"||V=="Chandan") {
    //do something
}
```

or

```
var V = $("#myInput").val();
var myArray = ["Kapil","Mayur","Abhinav","Chandan"];

if ($.inArray(V, myArray)!=-1) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Checking V against every value in the array manually like that is sloppy, since the autocomplete list might be very big, or change, etc. If he decides the autocomplete list should change tomorrow, he shouldn't have to update this code too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using jQuery, you can use the [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) method:

```
if($.inArray(enteredValue, myArray) == false) { ... } // If enteredValue is not in myArray
```

If you're just using plain Javascript, it is also simple:

```
if(myArray.indexOf(enteredValue) == -1) { ... } // If enteredValue is not in myArray
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this sample code for your autocomplete.

sample code..

```
    var url1 = sitepath+'opportunity/contact_autocomplete/';
        var related= '';
        $(function() {
            $( "#txtcontactid" ).autocomplete(
            {
                source:url1,
                select: function( event, ui ) 
                {
                    log( 
                         ui.item.id 
                      );
                }
            });
        });
```